# Creating a custom HTML page header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I'm in the middle of creating a html to pdf converter using the wkhtmltopdf application and having trouble trying to insert a custom header and footer to appear on the output document. For the program I am making this for I need these to be created within the html page that gets passed into the converter for packaging reasons. The wkhtmltopdf program won't accept the @media print css method so I was wondering if there was any other way in which this can be done within HTML,JavaScript, or CSS?

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  You want another program which converts html to pdf?

Comment: my apologies.. the problem isn't with the pdf converter, its with the adding a header/footer to a web page to be displayed at the top and bottom of a page in a pdf (paper pages not web pages). I'm looking for a way to create these within a html document without using the @media print option in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--header-html` and `--footer-html` options to pass in a URL or file path to the executable. [Documentation](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html#Headers%20And%20Footer%20Options)

If you are linking to the library use the object settings header and footer properties:
`settings.header.htmlUrl`